# What is the appropriate Python data structure to hold its items and a combined list of its items?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a list called `Materials`

```
MATERIALS = [
    'AR',
    'ARU',
    'ARC',
    'CON',
    'CSR',
    'MCR',
    'USF',
    ['AR', 'ARU', 'ARC', 'MCR', 'CSR'],
    ['AR', 'ARU', 'ARC', 'MCR'],
    ['AR', 'ARU', 'ARC'],
]
```

As you can see at first it stores each element alone, then does groupings of the elements.

**What is the appropriate data structure to store this mix-typed list?**

**Edit to reflect on comments below:**

1. By storing, I really mean, what is the appropriate way to store the variable in memory
2. This list illustrates the different test cases that will be fed into a numerical model. So, the first item is to model each item in MATERIALS.
3. I'd like to avoid redundancy as well as follow a best practice

Comment: You can homogenize the list by converting the first 7 elements to lists containing one item.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "store"?  If you mean store on disk, you need to serialize it first.  You can use the "pickle" or "json" module for that.

Comment: without knowing what you want to do with this data, it's kinda tough to say anything meaningful. There are several ways of storing this data, and without knowing its purpose, the best we can do is to enumerate all of them. So why don't you tell us how you plan to use this data so that we can suggest containers and argue their relative merits

Comment: I suppose you mean how you can avoid redundancy in the elements (so each element will be stored just one time, and the other occurrences will be just references)?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it now?

Comment: Do the items that aren't lists mean something different from the items that are lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for @joel-cornett comment, i.e. consistency in the type of data stored.

```
MATERIALS = [
    ['AR'],
    ['ARU'],
    ['ARC'],
    ['CON'],
    ['CSR'],
    ['MCR'],
    ['USF'],
    ['AR', 'ARU', 'ARC', 'MCR', 'CSR'],
    ['AR', 'ARU', 'ARC', 'MCR'],
    ['AR', 'ARU', 'ARC'],
]
```

If this doesn't suit you, then have two lists. And if you know in advance your models, you would preferably use variable than string:

```
AR = 'AR'
ARU = 'ARU'
ARC = 'ARC'
CON = 'CON'
CSR = 'CSR'
MCR = 'MCR'
USF = 'USF'

MATERIALS_SIMPLE = [
    AR,
    ARU,
    ARC,
    CON,
    CSR,
    MCR,
    USF,
]

MATERIALS = [
    [AR, ARU, ARC, MCR, CSR],
    [AR, ARU, ARC, MCR],
    [AR, ARU, ARC],
]
```

As long as you are not limited in terms of performance, I would tell you not to bother optimizing memory storage. For example, if you just need to process data, as long as your data is not bigger than your RAM, you're ok.

As for redundancy, if you mean that some lists share a common prefix and you want to exploit that, you could use a `trie` datastructure (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). But I don't recommend it because of the complexity and lack of readability.